# Can I install Python 2 packages in Python 3 using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

On my Python 3.6 installation, I just tried

```
pip install nipet
```

but I get this:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eef9zqvc\nipet\setup.py", line 64
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('e> the current operating system is not supported.')?
```

This is most probably related to `nipet` targeting Python 2.x.

I have successfully tried `2to3` on some part of this package, and noticed that all incompatibilities come down to `print` statements. However, since it is `setup.py` which fails, I cannot even install all the files in their proper location to run `2to3` on.

Is there some kind of `pip` wrapper for `2to3`that would allow me to install a Python 2.x package without much manual effort?

Comment: You should probably not try to patch a library while installing it. Check out the source code from the official repository, make it Python 3 compatible, check it back in. Sometimes it's trivial to port a package to Python 3, but usually it's a bit more work than just running `2to3` on it.

Comment: what if you do something like `pip3 install ...` and install the python 3 version (if exists)? Sometimes there are two python versions running

Comment: @ggdx `pip3 install nipet` results in the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL; DR: No, you can't.

---

[nipet](https://github.com/pjmark/NIPET) is not Python 3 compatible. As @deceze said in comment, you need to fix that before trying to install it. pip can't do the job.

Checkout the code and make it Python 3 (this may involve 2to3 and probably manual changes). Then retry to install it. If you're happy with what you got, you may submit your Python 3 port to the maintainer.

Also, nipet should be fixed to specify it is Python 2 only so that it is listed as Python 2 only on PyPI and pip3 does not even attempt to install if. You should open an issue in the bugtracker to ask the maintainer to fix that. Or even send a pull-request adding appropriate classifiers to setup.py, If you're comfortable doing that.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true what @Jérôme writes, this is not true for all components. For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention the `use_2to3` option of `setuptools`, which do most of what I wanted. (They do not touch setup.py, though, it seems).

Here is some more information:

> Setuptools provides a facility to invoke 2to3 on the code as a part of the build process, by setting the keyword parameter use_2to3 to True, but the Setuptools project strongly recommends instead developing a unified codebase using six, future, or another compatibility library.

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python3.html

Comment: +1 for completeness. But in practice, I wouldn't rely on that as a user. Developers might rely on it assuming they ensure it works on their codebase and the result works correctly. Even then, it is definitely not the recommended way.